# I receiving unknow data in my esp 8266

Tags: reset, esp8266, usart

I need upload my own program on esp8266 and i tried to upload a program for test and i see esp reset maybe evry 200 ms and i am receivig a lot of data on usart but isn't my data in program .data is something like exception and some bytes about stack and some data about load and reset again

this is my test code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define MAX_SRV_CLIENTS 1
#define TCP_PORT (23)      

WiFiServer tcpServer(TCP_PORT);
WiFiClient tcpServerClients[MAX_SRV_CLIENTS];

IPAddress apIP(192, 168, 1, 1);
const char SSID[] = "TCPUARTBridge";  
const char PASSWORD[] = "12345678";

#define SerialDebug Serial1
#define SerialGPS   Serial

#ifndef min
#define min(x,y)  ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
#endif

void setup() {
SerialDebug.begin(115200);
SerialDebug.println("TCP <-> UART bridge");

WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
WiFi.softAP(SSID, PASSWORD);

SerialGPS.begin(9600);

tcpServer.begin();
tcpServer.setNoDelay(true);
SerialDebug.print("Ready! Use 'telnet or nc ");
SerialDebug.print(WiFi.localIP());
SerialDebug.print(' ');
SerialDebug.print(TCP_PORT);
SerialDebug.println("' to connect");
}

void loop() {
uint8_t i;
char buf[1024];
int bytesAvail, bytesIn;

if (tcpServer.hasClient()) {
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
    if (!tcpServerClients[i] || !tcpServerClients[i].connected()) {
      if (tcpServerClients[i]) 
        tcpServerClients[i].stop();
        tcpServerClients[i] = tcpServer.available();
        SerialDebug.print("New client: "); SerialDebug.print(i);
        continue;
    }
  }

  WiFiClient tcpServerClient = tcpServer.available();
  tcpServerClient.stop();
}

for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
  if (tcpServerClients[i] && tcpServerClients[i].connected()) {

    while ((bytesAvail = tcpServerClients[i].available()) > 0) {
      bytesIn = tcpServerClients[i].readBytes(buf, min(sizeof(buf), bytesAvail));
        if (bytesIn > 0) {
          SerialGPS.write(buf, bytesIn);
          delay(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  while ((bytesAvail = SerialGPS.available()) > 0) {
    bytesIn = SerialGPS.readBytes(buf, min(sizeof(buf), bytesAvail));

    if (bytesIn > 0) {

      for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
        if (tcpServerClients[i] && tcpServerClients[i].connected()) {
    tcpServerClients[i].write((uint8_t*)buf, bytesIn);
        delay(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for reading this

Comment: We would need to see the exception trace for more info.

Comment: Thank you problem was power source and solved